# Equivalente de curl em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, libcurl

Estava aprendendo a usar *API's* de sites pra um projeto, e logo no começo fiquei com dificuldades e precisei perguntar.

Este era o exemplo de uso da *API* para testar credenciais no site, creio que seja *C++*:

```
curl -u user:password https://myanimelist.net/api/account/verify_credentials.xml
```

O problema é que eu comecei a aprender agora e foi pelo *Python 3*, então não faço a menor ideia do que o comando faz, muito menos de um equivalente em *Python*.

Depois de uns segundos eu pensei em usar algo com o `RobotBrowser` ou `urllib`, mas 
não tenho certeza se está certo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [Requests: HTTP for Humans](https://github.com/requests/requests) para consumir algum serviço de uma API ou fazer requisições comuns.

Veja um exemplo:

```
>>> import requests 

>>> r = requests.get("https://myanimelist.net/api/account/verify_credentials.xml", auth=('usuario', 'senha'))    
>>> r.text
```

Resposta:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
   <id>123456</id>
   <username>gato</username>
</user>
```

Você pode consultar [algumas formas para instalar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362600/how-to-install-requests-module-in-python-3-4-instead-of-2-7) o requests caso não tenha.

Aprenda mais [sobre o Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/#the-user-guide).

Comment: ajudou bastante, valeu